# Is every operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**Definition** : Let $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis.
  $T \in B(H)$ is **banded** if $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $
(Te_{n}, e_{m})\ne 0 \Rightarrow \vert n-m \vert \leq r$.

> Is every operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator ?

**Remark**: A *banded* operator is a thick generalization of a diagonal operator.
 It's also a finite sum of finite product of weight shift operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

N. Ozawa answered "no" [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137906/do-the-banded-operators-check-the-invariant-subspace-problem#comment355788_137906) :
 << The $C^{*}$-algebra on $ℓ^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by the banded operators (aka the uniform Roe algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$) is canonically isomorphic as $ℓ^{∞}(\mathbb{Z})⋊\mathbb{Z}$, which is nuclear and has tracial states (coming from invariant means on $\mathbb{Z}$). So, any operator which is unitarily equivalent to a banded operator generates an exact $C^{*}$-algebra having tracial states, which is not the case in general >>.

For more details, see the sections 16.3 and 16.4 of his [book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-88) with Nate Brown.

D. Voiculescu gave the first example of quasidiagonal operators which don't generate exact $C^{*}$-algebras:
*A note on quasidiagonal operators*, Operator Theory, 1988, 265-274.

Comment: Si tu fais les questions et aussi les réponses, ce n'est plus drole! En tous cas, c'est intéressant...

Comment: @Etienne Es ist verboten, Französisch zu sprechen.

Comment: Scusa, ma io non parlo il tedesco.

Comment: जुलिएन, अब यह एक आम प्रतिक्रिया है.

Comment: @Etienne: I have not yet the answer of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454135/is-every-irreducible-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator)...