# Is every irreducible operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

This issue continues this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452908/is-every-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator).

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**Definition** : Let $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis.
$T \in B(H)$ is **banded** if $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $
(Te_{n}, e_{m})\ne 0 \Rightarrow \vert n-m \vert \leq r$.

**Definition** : An operator $A \in B(H)$ is **irreducible** ([Halmos 1968](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Irreducible-operators/10.1307/mmj/1028999975.full)) if its commutant $\{ A\}'$ does not contain projections other than $0$ and $I$  (i.e., $A \ne A_{1} \oplus A_{2}$, or equivalently,  $\{A,A^{*}\}''=B(H)$).

> Is every irreducible operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator ?

**Remark**: A *banded* operator is a thick generalization of a diagonal operator.
It's also a finite sum of finite product of weight shift operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pooling the answers of N. Ozawa [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452908/is-every-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator/453971#453971) and  C. Eckhardt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455949/does-an-irreducible-operator-generate-an-exact-c-algebra/456157#456157) we can  answer "no" :

Indeed, if an operator is unitary equivalent to a banded operator, it generates an exact $C^{*}$-algebra, and there is an irreducible operator generating a non-exact $C^{*}$-algebra.

Conclusion, there is an irreducible operator which is not unitary equivalent to a banded operator.